# Take In Input from User and Display the same input on the same page

Tags: python, django, forms

Hi i am trying to create a post form in django where the user creates a post and the post is displayed back to them on the same page so far i have been unsuccessful. My articles display on the page but the form to post articles doesnt only the submit button shows.

views.py

```
def articles(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args ['posts'] = post.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    args ['full_name'] = User.objects.get(username = request.user.username)

    return render_to_response('articles.html', args)



def article(request, post_id=1):

    return render(request, 'article.html', 
                  {'post': post.objects.get(id=post_id) })

def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            a = form.save(commit=False)
            a.user = User.objects.get(username = request.user.username)
            a.save()

            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "You Article was added")

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/posts/all')
    else:
        form = PostForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('articles.html', args)
```

articles.html

```
<form action="/posts/create/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<ul>
{{form.as_ul}}
</ul>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Article">

</form>

{% if posts.count > 0 %}

{% for post in posts %}

    <div>
    <h2><a href="/posts/get/{{ post.id }}/">{{full_name}}</a></h2>
    <p>{{ post.body|lower|truncatewords:50 }}</p>
    <p>{{post.likes}} people liked this article</a></p>
    </div>

{% endfor %}

{% else %}

<p>None to show!</p>

{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',

        url(r'^create/$', 'posts.views.articles'),
        url(r'^get/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', 'posts.views.article'),
        url(r'^create/$', 'posts.views.create'),
        url(r'^like/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', 'posts.views.like_article'),
        url(r'^article/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', 'posts.views.add_comment'),
    )
```

Comment: You can use AJAX for displaying the submitted data per POST on the same page.

Comment: In your template you can remove the if-condition ``{% if posts.count > 0 %}``. That's obsolete. You can make this: ``{% for ... %} iterate {% else %} nothing there {% endfor %}``. Just replace ``{% endif %}`` with the statement ``{% endfor %}`` that is 3 lines above.

Comment: And you have ``{% endblock %}`` that doesn't start anywhere. I believe that it is properly done in your production code, but for the sake of esthetic and readability you should write it here correctly.

Comment: thanks cezar finally got it and also saw an example to use with ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you aren't passing the form to the template in articles().  You need to have something along the lines of:

```
args['form'] = YourForm()
```

In your first view function.  Also, in your create view you do this:

```
a.user = User.objects.get(username = request.user.username)
```

Which does an unnecessary database lookup of the user again, you can just do this to be clearer and faster:

```
a.user = request.user
```

Comment: Thanks frank @Frank Wiles